# How to drag and drop mp3 songs in the playlist

Tags: objective-c, macos, drag-and-drop, playlist, nsoutlineview

I am developing a mac desktop based application, Created some playlists using `NSOutlineView`. I know how to drag and drop in `NSTableView`, But i don't know how to drag and drop in the playlists according the attached image(*like iTunes application*) ,I am dragging some songs in the playlist 2.

[image: dragging the songs into playlist2]

Comment: Vineet Singh-- Any idea how to implement...???

Answer (score 0):

At the time of selecting the songs from NSTableView, store the selected songs id in a Array. After that when the mouse reach in NSOutlineView the following delegate methods will call that time user can add into the playlist table...

```
-(NSDragOperation)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView validateDrop:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)info proposedItem:(id)item proposedChildIndex:(NSInteger)index{
    return YES;
}
```

and

```
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)ov acceptDrop:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info item:(id)item childIndex:(NSInteger)childIndex{
    return YES;
}
```